# Wordpress / Buddypress – Paging, Permalinks, 404, page/2/

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, buddypress

Spent the good part of this morning working through this, but still…. apologies if this has been covered in a previous topic. Recently updated a site to BP 1.5, it worked GREAT except for one small thing. The permalinks and paging between custom post loops seems to be affected by the permalink redirects in BP 1.5 and is now redirecting to a WP 404.

Investigated this in detail before posting:

codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination

scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_Other_Issues

.htaccesss is being written to just fine by WP, no problems there. standard standard

Here are a few case studies of what’s happening:

1.) Paging added into templates displaying the homepage no longer works. example: www.sitename.com/page/2/ no longer works. In this particular scenario for some reason it redirects from www.sitename.com/page/2/ to www.sitename.com/2/

2.) Paging added into templates displaying custom post types still work correctly. example: www.sitename.com/custom-post-type-page-template/page/2/ works

3.) Paging added into templates displaying single group pages no longer works. example: www.sitename.com/groups/group-name/page/2/ does not work.

Did also discover this plug-in (wpcodesnippets.info/blog/wcs-custom-permalinks-hotfix.html), which solved the homepage issue but blew everything else up.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks thanks thanks.

To summarize in a clear question... how can I get this paging to work correctly in all 3 scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution, hope it help you [Paging fix plugin](http://barefootdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/11/fix-for-wordpress-paging-problem.html)